# Are multiple set's inside react functional components performant?

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

If I have a function in my react functional component and I would like to change the state of a few variables in "one shot" there, is there an efferent way to do that? I assume each time I set state it rerenders and I think I would like to avoid that. Also please correct me if I am wrong.

Example:

```
//imports here ..
function MyCard(props) {
    const [phoneInfo, setPhoneInfo] = useState(null);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    return (
        <Card>
                <Button
                    color="secondary"
                    onClick={async () => {
                      setPhoneInfo('some value here'); //will is rerun the function here?
                      setIsLoading(true); //will is rerun here again?
                      // possible to do both of these once?
                    }}>
                    Do Something
                </Button>
        </Card>
    );
}
export default MyCard;
```

Answer (score 1):

As you're updating multiple states from a single handler, and if you're using React 18, this won't cause a performance issue. Because it'll cause a batch update. Batching is when React groups multiple state updates into a single re-render for better performance. You can know more from [official doc](https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/29/react-v18.html) and from [git discussion](https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/21)

Comment: According to your links, automatic batching is performed in the OP's case even *before* React 18, because the updates are within a React event handler. (Though I notice that the OP's code has an unnecessary `async`, which suggests that his/her *real* code may be something more complicated, involving promises, that would not get batching in older versions.)

Comment: in my package.json i have "react": "^16.13.1" so I guess it's time to update to benefit from this performance?